# Continue increment on Date field using DayOfYear?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-formatting

I am looking to continue an increment from a date field and start the day of year from this particular date field.

For example (SQL SEVER):

```
(DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, CUSTOM_Date) -58) -- Decremented 58 Days to start
```

I am expecting then 'Jan 01' to continue numbering but instead it goes negative?[image]

Comment: Well 1 minus 59 is -58 (-57 probably due to a timezone conversion) so the calculation is correct. You might need to do a `CASE` where dayofyear is >=1 and < 59 then (DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, CUSTOM_Date) -59) + 306. Or make a table with the values and join it in. Or use DATEDIFF instead. There are a few ways you can tackle this.

Comment: Are you sure your logic is valid? It seems you should calculate differecnce from March, 1st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting exactly what it is supposed to do.  Jan 1 is the first day of a year. That means that the dayofyear for that date will be 1. If you subtract 59(or 58 in your case) from that number you'll get -57.
If you want it to keep incrementing, you'll need to have a start date and use DATEDIFF instead.
Use a variable with the true start date (I called it @startdate) and do the following:
`(DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdate, CUSTOM_date) -59)`
NOTE: I think in your screenshot you actually did -58, and not -59.